# systemctl returns no output, always exits 0. No units or unit files listed

Tags: systemd, 20.10

I just did an apt upgrade on my Ubuntu 20.10 installation, which I mention only because I can't think of anything else that could have possibly caused this. Now I can't get any output or non-zero exit code from any `systemctl` command that I can think of. For example:

- `systemctl list-unit-files --no-pager`
- `systemctl list-units --all --type=service --no-pager`
- `systemctl status dbus.service`
- `systemctl restart sshd.service`

I also tried them as root. Nothing, and no noticeable effect upon my system. The output of `journalctl -b -t systemd` isn't huge (558) and does show a few things starting. For example:

- systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
- systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.

This hasn't seemed to affect my desktop experience (gnome-shell) at all. I actually only noticed because I tried to install a snap, and it failed with a mount error. Then I tried some fixes and to restart snapd; which I couldn't via systemctl.

Any ideas?